# Best Practice - User Action in an Empty State

Tags: buttons, user-expectation, cta, empty-state

Is there an established best practice, backed up by research, that deals with an empty state with multiple CTA for the same action?

For example, this empty state from Dropbox:

[image]

There are multiple ways to 'Create a folder'. However, I'm concerned that if a user learns on first usage that the way to create a folder is to click the blue 'Create a Folder' button on the right, will the user not be confused when this button disappears when the empty state is no longer empty?

I am thinking it might be best to show an arrow to a button, 'Click here to create a folder' to teach the user an action that will remain consistent - that button will always be where a user goes to create folders.

Answer (score 1):

For the first time visitor what you are thinking is right, also if the user logs in after a long time. The system should understand that the user is logging in for first time or after a long time and show the arrows indicating the functions of those buttons. But, for the regular visitor it will become annoying.

I'm adding to show the arrows to the users who are logging in after a long time because over the time the sites features and functionalities might have changed or the user could have forgotten the use, so that will be helpful.

Edit:

The process is called [Onboarding](http://www.dtelepathy.com/blog/design/ux-flows-onboarding)

http://www.dtelepathy.com/blog/design/ux-flows-onboarding

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions separately -

- What is the least minimum input required by the user to move away
  from the empty state? Ideally, this action link is recommended as
  part of the empty state screen. By pointing towards a button that
  lets the user take further action, you are trying to move him away
  from his initial point of focus. It is much simpler for the user to
  take action at the point where his focus is currently at.
- The user will not be confused if your call to action buttons are
  appropriately visible based on your user research/user testing.

**To summarize :** 
Do not try to deviate user's attention. Minimize this by providing suitable actionable items at point of focus.